# Can I run apps in a smaller resolution?

Tags: applications, root-access, screen-resolution, samsung-galaxy-tab-4

I have a [Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 (SM-T235)](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_tab_4_7_0_lte-6241.php) tablet running Android version 4.4.2. It is 7 inch, which is nice, but sometimes (for example, when walking) I would like to be able to hold my device in one hand and only use my thumb to interact with the app that I am using. Perhaps even change the resolution so that is like a regular mobile device.

Basically I would like to have a way to run apps in a smaller resolution and have it not scaled to fit the display so that I can reach everything with my thumb using only one hand.

See the image below for an example that i have in mind.

*I have complete root access and am a developer (I don't really need 'simplified' answers, give me the tech details!)*

[image: explanatory image]

Comment: There should be an app to add additional apps to Multi-Window apps. Then simply pull on one of the corners and the app will scale (at least on my S6 Edge since Android 5.1.1).

Comment: @GiantTree I am running Android version 4.4.2 No such feature exists in this version. I am looking into updating if i find a good way to root that version.

Comment: @beeshyams I used **photoshop** on my laptop. [Here is my psd file!](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/c5dvya1j781obvi/fdospafknsap.psd)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run `su wm overscan LEFT,TOP,RIGHT,BOTTOM` from [Terminal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) *(Superuser privileges needed)*

If you do not have Superuser privileges, you can hook your phone to a PC and run ADB command
`adb shell wm overscan 200,200,0,0`

For example, to achieve what you've shown in the picture above try running
`wm overscan 200,200,0,0`.

But I must warn you, before running that, be sure you have USB debugging switched ON just in case overscan messes up your display, you can run
`adb shell wm overscan reset` from the PC connected.

[WindowManager (wm)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19846541/5181313) commands work on devices running [Android 4.3 and above](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/136904/can-i-run-apps-in-a-smaller-resolution/136920?noredirect=1#comment173958_136920)

*May require a Reboot to achieve proper re-size.*

---

Alternatively you can use [Niwatori module](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-niwatori-fly-apps-window-t3031680) if you have [Xposed](http://repo.xposed.info/) framework on your device.

Comment: [This is what it looks like](http://i.imgur.com/OVedDp4.png) on my device. Would not recommend.

Comment: @AndyC. You may have to change _density_ accordingly. Since that is device specific, you may have to experiment with different values specific to your device. You can use the Xposed module alternatively, if you find the process tedious.

Comment: reset is part of the command, so the backticks should cover `adb shell wm overscan reset` instead of `adb shell wm overscan`. Also, you would want to mention that wm is available only since Android 4.3. The rest of the world flocking towards this answer would end up being confused if they are running <4.3

Comment: @AndyC. You might need to restart/reboot so that all processes have adjusted their sizes.

Comment: @Firelord I think that on pre 4.3 you need to use am instead of wm... 
Also, I specified what version I am using, so it's fine the way it is. However it would be good to add the solutions for other versions as well for the sake of completion.

Comment: @WarButter: you should mention the version in the body of the question, not in the comments. Comments are second-class citizens and it would not be a reader's fault if they overlook them. // am doesn't have the capabilities overscan argument provides.  // Manubhargav: you didn't mention  (in the first part)that the user should be running the command with root privilege *in the terminal app*. It's not obvious to everyone. Without root access, you would end up with an error stating that you can't write Secure Settings. Note: I'm not forcing anyone to edit. Edit should be at your own discretion.